# Primefaces datatable drag and drop with pagination

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Is there any way to **drag-and-drop rows between pages** in Primefaces datatable? I found out it's easy to implement drag-and-drop but I don't see option to move rows between pages when I have a lot of rows.

I used this example

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/reorder.xhtml

Comment: No there is not... Sorry

Comment: Okay then, I guess I'll just implement some buttons to move the rows. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, you have written **columns** in bold and in the rest talk about rows... confusing (although the answer stays the same)

Comment: @Kukeltje will edit, I meant rows. Sorry